# Python GIT CHeckout failed due to: exit code(1)

Tags: python, git, gitlab, checkout

i have an git repo in gitlab. I tried to checkout the master branch with the following lines.

```
repo = git.Repo(os.path.dirname(__file__), search_parent_directories=True)
repo.git.checkout("master")
ref_repo_root = os.path.join(WORKING_DIRECTORY, 'ref_decoders')
```

But i got the following error.

```
E   git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
E     cmdline: git checkout master
E     stderr: 'error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.'
```

What i know repo.git.checkout("HEAD~1") works fine. Where is my issue?

Comment: Is there in fact a branch named `master`? That isn't exactly guaranteed any more - for political reasons, some hosting services arrange things (or give you setup steps to arrange things) to name the primary branch something else.

Comment: To be clear, are you using [this package](https://pypi.org/project/python-git/) to interface with git? Or something else?

Comment: Hi Karl, i use the following python-git package.

Comment: What branches does the repository have? Run `git branch -a`.

Comment: This repository has an master an other branches. I tried to checkout all this branches. But the issue is the same. And it's works for Head~1

Comment: Hi, is in my Case an fetch --all needed ? Because i got the hint. If the Branchname not known than i will get this errror.

Answer (score 2):

The default branch in gitlab since v14.0 is `main` and not `master`.
Read here for more info: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/03/10/new-git-default-branch-name/

Comment: Hi, thanks for this hint. But i got the same issue. E   git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
E     cmdline: git checkout main
E     stderr: 'error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git.'

Comment: Does the master/main branch exist at all?

Comment: Hi Gabip, the master does exist.

Comment: You mentioned that `repo.git.checkout("HEAD~1")` works. What branch does git think you're on currently (what does it say in `git status`)?